# error: ‘class QModelIndex’ has no member named ‘siblingAtColumn’

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview

I was using `sibilingAtColumn` to get data from qtableview.
The code was compiled successfully on MacOS, however it raised error when compiling on linux.
The Error was `error: ‘class QModelIndex’ has no member named ‘siblingAtColumn’`.
How to solve this problem

Comment: [`siblingAtColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#siblingAtColumn) has been introduced in Qt 5.11. Are you sure, that you've got proper Qt version on your linux machine?

Comment: I check my travis-ci and saw Qt 5.9. I think that's the issue. Thank you very much for noticing that!